# Could anyone tell me why / how this XSS vector works in the browser?

Tags: xss, security

I have suffered a number of XSS attacks against my site. The following HTML fragment is the XSS vector that has been injected by the attacker:

```
<a href="mailto:">
<a href=\"http://www.google.com onmouseover=alert(/hacked/); \" target=\"_blank\">
<img src="http://www.google.com onmouseover=alert(/hacked/);" alt="" /> </a></a>
```

It looks like script shouldn't execute, but using IE9's development tool, I was able to see that the browser translates the HTML to the following:

```
<a href="mailto:"/>
<a onmouseover="alert(/hacked/);" href="\"http://www.google.com" target="\"_blank\"" \?="">
</a/>
```

After some testing, it turns out that the \" makes the "onmouseover" attribute "live", but i don't know why. Does anyone know why this vector succeeds?

Comment: Seems the \" is commenting out the ", leaving the quote to be a part of the (invalid) url. You can have attribute values without quotes in HTML. 
<img src=xyz onerror=alert(1) > is also valid. But this is interesting. I did not know that \" worked like that.

Comment: Seems any character in front of the ", turns it into a part of the attribute value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So to summarize the comments:
Sticking a character in front of the quote, turns the quote into a part of the attribute value instead of marking the beginning and end of the value. 
This works just as well:

```
href=a"http://www.google.com onmouseover=alert(/hacked/); \"
```

HTML allows quoteless attributes, so it becomes two attributes with the given values.